# how to change text field depending on other field

Tags: javascript, html

i want to change text box value depend on other field ,  i did but not working and getting zero in "resoom" field ,

```js
<script>
function resoome(){
 var get_balance=document.getElementById("Etisalat").value
 var alfees;
switch(get_balance){
  case get_balance>=0.5 && get_balance<=1:
    alfees=0.10;
    break;
    case get_balance>1 && get_balance<=3:
    alfees=0.15;
    break;
    case get_balance>3 && get_balance<=5:
    alfees=0.25;
    break;
    case get_balance>5 && get_balance<=10:
    alfees=0.50;
    break;
    case get_balance>10 && get_balance<=15:
    alfees=0.60;
    break;
    case get_balance>15 && get_balance<=20:
    alfees=0.70;
    break;
    case get_balance>20 && get_balance<=30:
    alfees=0.80;
    break;
    case get_balance>30 && get_balance<=40:
    alfees=0.90;
    break;
    case get_balance>40 && get_balance<=70:
    alfees=1;
    break;
    case get_balance>70 && get_balance<=100:
    alfees=1.25;
    break;
    case get_balance>100 && get_balance<=150:
    alfees=1.50;
    break;
    case get_balance>150 && get_balance<=200:
    alfees=2;
    break;
    case get_balance>200:
    alfees=3;
    break;
     default:
        alfees=0;
  }
  resoom.value=alfees;
  }
</script>
```

```html
 <select name="Etisalat" id="Etisalat" onfocusout="resoome()" class="select Etisalat">
        <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="1.5">1.5</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>

<input type="number" id="resoom"style="width:90px"  name="resoom" placeholder="الرسوم"/>
```

How i can solve it and make the resoom value changing depending on the other feild
Thanks

Comment: I believe your problem might be with how you read the value of select. Try using this instead: `var get_balance=parseFloat(document.getElementById("Etisalat").value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function resoome() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Etisalat").value;
    var get_balance = parseInt(x);
    var alfees;
    switch (true) {
        case get_balance > 0 && get_balance <= 1 : 
            alfees = 0.10;
            break;
        case get_balance > 1 && get_balance <= 3:
            alfees = 0.15;
            break;
        case get_balance > 3 && get_balance <= 5:
            alfees = 0.25;
            break;
        case get_balance > 5 && get_balance <= 10:
            alfees = 0.50;
            break;
        case get_balance > 10 && get_balance <= 15:
            alfees = 0.60;
            break;
        case get_balance > 15 && get_balance <= 20:
            alfees = 0.70;
            break;
        case get_balance > 20 && get_balance <= 30:
            alfees = 0.80;
            break;
        case get_balance > 30 && get_balance <= 40:
            alfees = 0.90;
            break;
        case get_balance > 40 && get_balance <= 70:
            alfees = 1;
            break;
        case get_balance > 70 && get_balance <= 100:
            alfees = 1.25;
            break;
        case get_balance > 100 && get_balance <= 150:
            alfees = 1.50;
            break;
        case get_balance > 150 && get_balance <= 200:
            alfees = 2;
            break;
        case get_balance > 200:
            alfees = 3;
            break;
        default:
            alfees = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById("resoom").value = alfees;
}
```

1.Get variable(get_balance) value as a number using parseInt function.
2.As the expression you have used in cases returns either true or false,use true in switch case.

Comment: it working well but i got "0" instead "0.1" when "Etisalat" field carrying "0.5" ?

Comment: Use parseFloat instead of ParseInt